# Why does vminpoly not work for ie8 and below?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, polyfills

What im trying to use is a polyfill for the new vw unit. My question is however why it not works in ie8 and below. The developer says all browsers ie5 - 8 are supported...including opera mini...

This is the link to the script. It includes a demo https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly

What is wrong? Why doesnt this work?

Comment: maybce some code, example how we should help you. You expect magican anwser?..

Comment: Are you getting errors in your console output? Do you have a specific demo that we can troubleshoot? How are you testing in IE8; emulating IE8 in a later browser, or running a native instance of IE8 on a virtual machine, or maybe in BrowserStack?

Comment: @JonathanSampson yes, my post has a link to the demo and code. http://saabi.github.io/vminpoly/demo2.html  im testing with a real internet explorer 7 on vista. I also tested it with windows 7 internet explorer 10 using developer tools. Ie7 and 8 do show errors, even as emulation.

Comment: It seems to be working for me in IE8; can you take a screenshot of what you're seeing, and share any errors in the console?

Comment: @JonathanSampson I get a blank screen as if the demo is empty...all just white. Bottom left internet explorer 7 shows some sort of error in line 278, symbol 11. The object does not support this property. Ie7 does not have dev tools so I cant really see. It does work for you though. It is all responsive in ie8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your experience appears to be different than mine. I accessed the demo in both Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8. I checked console output for errors in 8, and saw none. I modified the Browser Mode in 8 to reflect 7, switched from Standards to Quirks, and more. In all of my efforts, I could not cause the demo to give me the results you're reporting.

Below are my results from Internet Explorer 8.

[image]

Comment: Very unusual. Maybe it is my testing laptop which is vista with 500 mb ram. Maybe it is cpu or ram heavy...not sure what is happening. Very confusing stuff. Do you have any idea if this has to do with the operating system Vista? On what windows were you testing? My case must be special

Comment: The unusual thing is it doesnt work on my windows 7 either when tested via dreamweavers ie preview mode. Could it be because of flash? Or maybe sonething else?

Comment: I have no idea what "IE Preview Mode" is, but I can assure you that it shouldn't be considered a reliable representation of Internet Explorer. Test directly in IE to know what IE supports. BrowserStack.com is great for testing directly in any number of browsers (including most versions of IE).

Comment: you are right. What I tried was previewing the code with internet explorer using dreamweaver. I also tested it directly in IE using a vista native internet explorer 7 and a windows seven ie10 using developer tools. All methods fail. BrowserStack works though, but why? How come my native ie7 doesnt show anything, not even when emulating ie8 with ie10 dev tools. If it works in browserstack it should work on other peoples ie5-8 too

Comment: @user3025918 I'm not sure what could be happening for your environment; I'd be happy to join you in a google Hangout to troubleshoot.

Comment: That would be super. I dont have hangout though. I will check it out

Comment: @user3025918 All you need is a Google account. Look me up on twitter and let me know if I can ever assist with cross-browser, or IE-specific, solutions.

Comment: that would be great. I will send you a message and a friend invite.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of vminpoly. I'd be happy to join that troubleshooting hangout with both of you, let me know.